# Electron Instance Communication

Tags: electron, protocols, instance, message, communication

I'm trying to figure out a way to communicate between Electron instances. The app I'm working on allows multiple instances each associated with a file. I want to be able to broadcast a message, from an instance spawned from a protocol, to all instances.

If I acquire a lock on the first instance using `app.requestSingleInstanceLock()`, I can use the event `second-instance` to send a message but only to that first instance.

I've also tried enumerating all the windows with `BrowserWindow.getAllWindows()` but it looks like those refer to instances created within the electron instances.

Using Electron: 9.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any "nice" way. I think you just need to have one app write to a file via the `fs` module when it wants to communicate, and the app instances that are expecting to receive messages must watch this file for changes like so:

```
fs.watchFile("myLogFile.log", (curr, prev) => {
   // read file for the message
});
```

Comment: This solution worked for me. I used a `fs.watch` + `app.getPath('appData')` to get the message across instances.